# Updating all rows in one table who have 1 match, more than 1 match, or 0 matches in other table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE huge (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR2(100),
    day INT,
    errno INT,
    error_message VARCHAR2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE smallish (
   id INT PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR2(100),
   day int
);

-- Note the lack of a foreign key between huge and smallish on name
-- This is intentional
```

I want to do three things:

1. Update all rows in `huge` to have the `day` set to that in `smallish` where the rows in `huge` have exactly one `name` in `smallish`.
2. Update all rows in `huge` to have an `errno` of `1` and an `error_message` of `:name not in smallish` where the rows in `huge` do not have a name in `smallish`.
3. Update all rows in `huge` to have an `errno` of `2` and an `error_message` of `:name has multiple rows in smallish` where the rows in `huge` have more than one `name` in `smallish`

I'm using the following DML's which appear to work, but two of them give full table scans on huge in the output and otherwise don't look intuitive.

Additionally it would be pretty cool to do this all in one statement as opposed to three.

Update:

The following appears to work and looks somewhat intuitive, but the explain plan shows a full table scan on huge:

```
UPDATE huge h_out
SET (day, errno, error_message) = (
    select CASE WHEN DAY IS NOT NULL AND count = 1 THEN day ELSE NULL END as bill_day,
           CASE WHEN day IS NULL THEN 1 WHEN count > 1 THEN 2 ELSE NULL END AS errno,
           CASE WHEN day IS NULL THEN name || ' not in smallish' WHEN count > 1 THEN name || ' has multiple rows in smallish' ELSE NULL END as error_message
    FROM (
        select dhuge.name, max(smallish.day) as day, count(dhuge.name) as count
        from (select distinct huge.name from huge) dhuge left join smallish on dhuge.name = smallish.name
        group by dhuge.name
    ) h_in
    WHERE h_out.name = h_in.name
);
```

Original:

```
-- Problem #1
UPDATE huge h
SET (day) = (
    SELECT MIN(day)
    FROM smallish s
    WHERE h.name = s.name
    GROUP BY s.name
    HAVING count(1) = 1
) WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT null
    FROM smallish s
    WHERE s.name = h.name
);

-- Problem #2 Explain plan shows a full table scan on huge
UPDATE huge h_out
SET (errno, error_message) = (
    select 1, h_out.name || ' not in smallish' AS error_message FROM DUAL
) WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM smallish s
    WHERE s.name = h_out.name
);


-- Problem #3 Explain plan shows a full table scan on huge
UPDATE huge h
SET (errno, error_message) = (
    SELECT 2, h.name || ' has multiple rows' FROM dual
) WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT s.name
    FROM smallish s
    WHERE h.name = s.name
    GROUP BY s.name
    HAVING count(1) > 1
);
```

---

To replicate:

```
DROP TABLE huge;
DROP TABLE smallish;

CREATE TABLE huge (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR2(100),
    day INT,
    errno INT,
    error_message VARCHAR2(100)
);


CREATE TABLE smallish (
   id INT PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR2(100),
   day int
);

create index huge_name_indx ON huge (name);
create index smallish_name_indx ON smallish (name);

insert into huge values (1, 'good1', null, 0, null);
insert into huge values (2, 'good1', null, 0, null);
insert into huge values (3, 'good1', null, 0, null);
insert into huge values (4, 'good1', null, 0, null);
insert into huge values (5, 'good2', null, 0, null);
insert into huge values (6, 'good2', null, 0, null);
insert into huge values (7, 'good2', null, 0, null);
insert into huge values (8, 'good2', null, 0, null);
insert into huge values (9, 'double1', null, 0, null);
insert into huge values (10, 'double1', null, 0, null);
insert into huge values (11, 'double1', null, 0, null);
insert into huge values (12, 'double1', null, 0, null);
insert into huge values (13, 'double2', null, 0, null);
insert into huge values (14, 'double2', null, 0, null);
insert into huge values (15, 'double2', null, 0, null);
insert into huge values (16, 'double2', null, 0, null);
insert into huge values(17, 'notin1', null, 0, null);
insert into huge values(18, 'notin1', null, 0, null);
insert into huge values(19, 'notin1', null, 0, null);
insert into huge values(20, 'notin1', null, 0, null);
insert into huge values(21, 'notin2', null, 0, null);
insert into huge values(22, 'notin2', null, 0, null);
insert into huge values(23, 'notin2', null, 0, null);
insert into huge values(24, 'notin2', null, 0, null);

insert into smallish values (1, 'good1', 1);
insert into smallish values (2, 'good2', 2);
insert into smallish values (3, 'double1', 3);
insert into smallish values (4, 'double1', 4);
insert into smallish values (5, 'double2', 5);
insert into smallish values (6, 'double2', 6);

commit;
```

Answer (score 2):

To do this all in one statement, you can use `merge`:

```
merge into huge h
    using (select name, count(*) as cnt, max(day) as day
           from smallish
           group by name
          ) s
    on h.name = s.name
when matched then update
    set day = (case when s.cnt = 1 then s.day else h.day end),
        errno = (case when s.cnt > 1 then 2 else h.errno end),
        error_message = (case when s.cnt > 1 then s.name || ' has multiple rows in smallish' else error_message end)
when not matched then update
    set errno = 1,
        error_message = h.name || ' not in smallish';
```

Comment: In Oracle, it seems to be giving an error because of the use of `update` twice. Toad says `Found 'update' expecting 'insert'`. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you meant to wrap `h.name - s.name` in parenthesis and include an `END` on the case statement for the matched error_message.

Comment: How many rows is huge; and how many rows in huge are being updated?

Comment: @BobC I suppose over time, hundreds of millions of rows could be in huge, although for a given update there should only be 1-10 million rows. The example I listed is a bit contrived; in reality there would be another column called "batch_id" that would be used in the where clause to restrict the number of rows to 1-10 million.

Comment: The reason I ask, is that sometimes a strategy of "transformation" rather than "modification" can be considered. Update is a very expensive operation. Not only do you have the update itself, but you have undo and redo. So everything is a triple write. However, if you can re-write the table (or partition) with the new data, you can take advantage of techniques like direct path load, parallelism etc. Often this is orders of magnitude faster then doing an update.

Comment: @BobC when you say re-write the table, do you mean delete the rows and then reinsert?

Comment: @MatthewMoisen Half right. I would not delete, I would (eventually) drop. So I would create a new table; do an insert /*+ append */ ...   drop the original table, and then rename.

Answer (score 0):

Merge above looks very promising, but you cannot use it for not matching names (syntax limitations) - a separate UPDATE is required for that and probably you will not avoid full table scan.
I like using "IN (subquery)" as it usually gives very good explain plans.
Try these:

```
UPDATE huge SET ...
WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM smallish GROUP BY name HAVING count(*) = 1);

UPDATE huge SET ...
WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM smallish GROUP BY name HAVING count(*) > 1);

UPDATE huge SET ...
WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM smallish);
```

Making huge_name_indx a BITMAP index could help too.

BTW, Tom Kyte suggests to create a new table with updated data rather than update existing huge tables (https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/asktom.search?tag=how-to-update-millions-or-records-in-a-table-200211).